# Does every US state set its standard deduction to match the federal one? Why?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

The United States' 2017 [Tax Cuts and Jobs Act](https://www.investopedia.com/taxes/trumps-tax-reform-plan-explained/) nearly doubled the U.S. *federal* income tax's standard deduction from its 2017 level, starting in 2018. My state also increased its income tax standard deduction to match the new federal one.

Did every U.S. state (with an income tax) nearly double its standard deduction to match the federal one in 2018? If so, why? Wouldn't this represent a massive unplanned *state* income tax cut, leading to greatly disrupted state budgets?

More generally, does any U.S. state (with an income tax) choose to set its standard deduction differently from the U.S. federal income tax's standard deduction? If not, why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I live in Virginia. When the Federal government almost doubled the standard deduction and removed the personal exemption, some states made a similar change to the standard deduction. The legislature in Virginia debated for an entire year before deciding not to adjust their standard deduction.

There were multiple political reasons for this debate. There were also some financial ones.

Virginia realized that there were two connected issues related to this change in Federal deduction. Many households that previously itemized their deductions on the 1040 would now be switching to the standard deduction. Virginia tax code required the itemize-or-standard-deduction choice on the state tax form match the decision on the federal form.

That meant that a taxpayer had to decide which saved them the most money. In most cases the standard deduction saved them more money on the federal form, than it cost them money of the state form.  Therefore extra money was going to flow into the state coffers.

How to address this became a political question. In the end they didn't make any changes that year.

Now years later, the state is starting to address the issue by adjusting the state standard deduction.

States had to decide what to do. They needed to adjust their tax code. Some did. Some didn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "removed the personal exemption"? Isn't there still $930 exemption per person? https://www.tax.virginia.gov/sites/default/files/taxforms/individual-income-tax/2022/760-2022.pdf Will that be eliminated in the future?

Comment: @DavePhD the personal exemption was removed at the federal level.

Comment: thanks, I understand now

Answer (score 22):

*Most* States "conform" to the Federal tax code and basically say "whatever is income or deductions for Federal - is also for us", but not all. Some States conform to a specific snapshot of the Federal code ([California](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=RTC&sectionNum=17024.5) and [Texas](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/TX/htm/TX.171.htm#171.0001), for example), others conform only to parts of the code (for example only conform to the individual tax code, or only to corporate code, or only to some other part of the code). Worth noting that Texas doesn't have income tax per se (they have franchise tax for other entities), but it still codified its IRC conformity.

The [map here](https://us.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/advocacy/tax/downloadabledocuments/aicpa-state-conformity-to-irc.pdf) shows which states conform to the Federal code, and how.

In this regard, "conforming" means using the same calculation to decide what's included in the income, and is usually done by just taking the AGI from the Federal tax form. The standard/itemized deduction is not part of that computation as it happens after the AGI is determined (what is called "below the line"), yet some states do conform to that as well. Not all States have standard deductions though, some only have personal exemptions (Federal personal exemptions were zeroed out by the TCJA).

Here's the [list of States and how they handle standard/itemized deductions](https://kb.drakesoftware.com/Site/Browse/16450/States-Generally-Standard-or-Itemized-Deduction), here's a [list of states and their standard deduction amounts](https://taxfoundation.org/publications/state-individual-income-tax-rates-and-brackets/).

As to why... Some states choose to be fully conformant to the IRC to remove the burden of managing their own code, others choose not to to retain the flexibility of setting their own tax policy.

Comment: I understand the practical benefits of copying the federal code, but it seems strange that they would continue to do so when the federal code undergoes a drastic change like the TC&JA. Since state governments (except Vermont) are constitutionally required to balance their budgets, wouldn't the sudden federal tax cut prompt a big involuntary state budget cut? That seems like a high price to pay for administrative simplicity.

Comment: I don't believe that the map linked to is all that reliable. I know that Illinois computes Illinois taxable income differently from "whatever is income or deductions for Federal - is also for us"

Comment: @tparker "Since state governments (except Vermont) are constitutionally required to balance their budgets". It's [much more complicated](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/what-are-state-balanced-budget-requirements-and-how-do-they-work) than that. 2 states have no balanced budget requirement, 9 states are "weak", and 8 states have statutory instead of constitutional BBRs.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Illinois tax form starts with the Federal AGI. They do conform to the IRC in that regard, including the above-the-line deductions. I'll correct my answer to reflect that

Comment: "Some States conform to a specific snapshot of the Federal code (California and Texas, for example)..." I don't understand that. Texas has no income tax whatsoever. California does.

Comment: At least Texas and Nevada have no income tax.  They get their income in other ways.

Comment: @Wastrel actually... See Texas Tax Code Sec. 171.0001(9). It is true that Texas doesn't have individual income tax, but it is also true that they pin their IRC conformity to a specific date.

Comment: @littleadv Thank you. I see now. Texas uses many provisions of the IRC, including deductions, to compute state franchise taxes. Texas probably does something similar for other taxes as well.

Answer (score 10):

It simplifies taxes if they do.

The Federal tax code has a complex process by which you arrive at tax. Frankly, this process is *most of* filling out a tax form, with dozens of supplemental schedules that tack onto that part of the form.

So by simply cloning the "up to tax" part of the Federal form, they make things a lot simpler for taxpayers and tax preparers.  They can even tell the taxpayer "Just include a photocopy of page 1 of your Federal tax, with your state tax".  Then the state tax pages can focus on state adjustments.

Politically, it also takes a lot less of the Legislature's limited bandwidth to decide to clone the Federal process, as opposed to the political Manhattan Project of "growing their own" tax code from scratch.

It also allows them to coattail on the large body of Federal case law that already interprets the Federal tax law.  So it saves bandwidth in the courts too.

Comment: My question was about the standard deduction, but your answer talks about the AGI calculation. Aren't those separate parts of the process of filling out one's tax form?

Comment: @tparker good point, let me correct that scope. The same basic facts apply.

Answer (score 5):

> More generally, does any U.S. state (with an income tax) choose to set its standard deduction differently from the U.S. federal income tax's standard deduction? If not, why not?

Illinois has no standard deduction at all but it does have a personal exemption of about $2000 per person. As far as I can remember, this exemption did not increase when the Federal standard deduction did (and the Federal personal exemption was eliminated).  Illinois does begin with the Federal AGI as the starting point but then modifies the Federal AGI in several ways to determine the taxable income for Illinois income tax purposes. The modifications include standard stuff like deducting interest paid by US Government obligations, adding on municipal bond income from bonds issued by other states, but most important -- *deducting all retirement income such as pension payments, IRA and 401(k) withdrawals, and Social Security payments* from Federal AGI to arrive at the Illinois AGI.  Illinois also charges a flat tax rate (as required by the State Constitution) of 4.95%  on the Illinois taxable income with no special rates for long-term capital gains or qualified dividends.